# "Cannot GET /" error when deploying Nuxt Vue.js application to Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, vue.js, nuxt.js

I get a "500 Server Error" when I deploy my Nuxt application.

[image]

Below are my configuration files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An App",
  "author": "Me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "postinstall": "nuxt build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.0.0",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^0.6.0",
    "@firebase/storage": "^0.2.3",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Previously my `start` was `nuxt start` and i do not have `deploy`
https://github.com/kamatte-me/nuxt-gae-se/blob/master/package.json
But still get the same error.

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs8
env :  standard
```

I also referred and attempted to try out the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993485/deploy-nuxt-js-to-google-app-engine-return-502-bad-gateway?rq=1) and [here](https://qiita.com/kai_kou/items/2d50d9e91e536fd4aeb2) but doesn't work. Note that my application does not have a `server.js` or `app.js`, so i cannot use those.

### Update

I did a workaround using the below approach (so can ignore everything above unless you need it as additional reference).

I added a server.js (exactly same as theirs) following https://github.com/kamatte-me/nuxt-gae-se and updated my package.json to such:

```
{
  "name": "my-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A App",
  "author": "Me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "deploy": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "postinstall": "nuxt build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.0.0",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^0.6.0",
    "@firebase/storage": "^0.2.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3", //<-added this as suggested by kamette
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Now my error is this:

[image]

Any idea?

I have this in my Navigation.vue:

```
 <nuxt-link to="/" exact>Dashboard</nuxt-link>
```

In addition, the error logs I saw:

[image]

[image]

After adding "nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3" to the dependencies as advised by kamatte, I am seeing back the "500 Server Error" again, logs doesn't show anything useful (I have clicked "Load newer logs" many times already, this is the latest...)

[image]

Comment: `"start": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt start"` maybe?

Comment: @yeen is any reverse proxy ??

Comment: @iambatman I use the default settings from Google App Engine. Didn't do advanced configuration. Just want to deploy my app that is working on my localhost:3000

Comment: @XanderLuciano That doesn't work. I got "nuxt" from https://github.com/kamatte-me/nuxt-gae-se/blob/master/package.json I assumed is the parameter in "dev". But they using "node server.js" cos their dev is using "node server.js", so i used "nuxt" instead

Comment: @XanderLuciano i made some changes, now another error

Comment: can you check for errors in your log please? @yeeen 
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: @XanderLuciano I have uploaded some logs screenshot, can you help to take a look? I don't understand the error...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This question was (and perhaps still is) in a bit of a state. I have removed the txtspk ('u' meaning 'you') and the urgent begging, but I'm concerned that potentially substantive updates were being made even after an answer came in. Once you get an answer, it is best either to make amendments at the end of the question (i.e. in the correct chronological order for new readers, in a clearly-marked edit/update) or ask a new question.

Comment: Adding "update" at the start is just perplexing for the readers who will see this in three months time (you _need_ to write for them too), so it is best to refrain from doing that entirely. I have attempted to repair this.

Comment: @halfer Ok.......

Answer (score 1):

Express.js and nuxt-sass-resources-loader must be included in package.json.

.e.g.)
package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "nuxt-sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3"
},
```

Otherwise, Express.js will not be installed on the GAE.
It seems that it worked because you already installed Express.js in your local environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after adding it is still not working, I got the same error

Comment: added the nuxt-sass-resources-loader, now "500 Server Error" again